# Definir conexão de acordo com dados do usuário logado

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5.3

Criei uma segunda conexão no meu arquivo config/database.php e irei criar também uma terceira, queria saber como posso fazer pra alternar entre essas conexões de acordo com o usuário logado.

**config/database.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'database2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => ('localhost'),
            'port' => ('3306'),
            'database' => ('database2'),
            'username' => ('root'),
            'password' => (''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

Sei que posso escolher a conexão no meu model dessa forma, mas como faço pra que esse nome "*database2*" seja puxado do usuário logado ao invés de ser colocado o nome diretamente ali?

```
class Empresa extends Model
{
    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->connection = 'database2';
    }
}
```

Tentei colocar dessa forma, mas não funcionou.

```
return $this->connection = Auth::user()->database;
```

Deu esse erro.

> ErrorException in Empresa.php line 16:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Posso ter infinitos usuários para cada database, isso seria inviável. E sim, é exatamente uma forma de fazer essa ligação que eu preciso conforme foi explicado na pergunta.

Comment: Não é isso @Alvejado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notei que você está tentando acessar os dados do usuário sem verificar se o mesmo está autenticado ou não. É preciso definir um comportamento caso o usuário não está conectado.

Da maneira que você fez provavelmente deu erro por o usuário não estar logado. Se você tentar chamar os dados do usuário antes de ele estar logado, vai aparece o erro `Try to get a property of a non-object`.

## Um problema no Auth do Laravel 5

Outra coisa ainda é que porque o Middleware `web` pode nem ter sido executado no momento da chamada de `Auth::user()`. Nesse caso, se o middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` não for executado (e ele está dentro do grupo `web`, os dados de `Auth::user()` não serão carregados, pois o middleware seria processado após o processamento da rota.

Então duas coisas: Se você precisa processar os dados de Autenticação em outros lugares da aplicação (como em Service Provider por exemplo), seria interessante fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

    // Pequena alteração. Inicialização de cookies, sessão e erros devem ser incluídos o quanto antes, por contas das requisições que retornam erros

    \Tmt\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // \Tmt\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        // \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

        \Tmt\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
```

## Solução

O ensinamento principal que eu gostaria de explicar nessa resposta é esse: seria interessante criar um `Middleware` para definir a conexão padrão de acordo com o usuário:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    auth()->check() && config(['database.default' => auth()->user()->database]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: eu fiz o mesmo comentário que você sobre usuário tem que estar autenticado, criar um `middleware` vai causar problemas porque o usuário faz parte de outro conexão? não vai ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu deixei bem claro que o uso do middleware é para uma conexão padrão. Se ele for definir uma conexão para cada model, daí ele vai ter que fazer isso ou no model ou no controller. Só que isso aí você já respondeu :p

Comment: só foi um lembrete, porque, isso que você fez para esse determinado caso, só funciona uma vez para conexões dinâmicas ou fazer até a configuração fixa no model User também funciona. vai depender do usuário nos dar um feedback

Comment: Consegui fazer com o Middleware @WallaceMaxters. Ainda estou fazendo alguns testes, mas creio que essa solução cai bem no meu caso

Answer (score 0):

A lógica inicial seria, os usuários (`user`) teria uma ***conexão padrão configurada***. Após a autenticação do usuário crie instâncias das `classes` que herdam do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) (`os models`) da seguinte forma:

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CreditosController extends Controller 
{
    private $credito;
    public function __construct()
    {
        // pode fazer injeção pelo construtor também ...
        $this->credito = new App\Models\Creditos(); 

        $this->credito->setConnection(Auth::user()->database);
    }
}
```

a mudança na ***conexão*** desse `model`. O processo seria feito no `Controller`, sim e talvez direto, mas, não recomendaria.

- [Multiple DB Connections in Laravel](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)
- [$this setConnection(string $name)](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setConnection)

Comment: A lógica inicial está certa, mas não consegui entender como implementar. Esse setConnection é no controller?

Comment: @RaylanSoares fiz uma edição, verifique se está bom!